# How can I improve the computational efficiency of looping over numpy linear solve

Tags: python, numpy, loops, linear-algebra

I have a system of equations that I need to solve for a large number of variables. The code is more complicated than below, but the problem is as follow:

I have an iterator:

```
iterator= np.arange(2000)   # array!
```

And arrays dependent on a function of that iterator:

```
A_11 = function_A11(iterator)
A_12 = function_A12(iterator)
A_21 = function_A21(iterator)
A_22 = function_A22(iterator)

B_1 = function_B1(iterator)
B_2 = function_B2(iterator)

X = np.zeros(2, 2000)

for i, (A11, A12, A21, A22, B1, B2) in enumerate(zip(A_11, A_12, A_21, A_22, B_1, B_2):
    A = np.array([[A11, A12],[A21,A22]]) 
    B = np.array([B1, B2])
    X[:,i] = np.linalg.solve(A,B)
```

The method works but it is computationally expensive and I have the feeling that I should be able to optimize this, e.g. by working with 3D arrays. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Tim

Comment: If you have to apply the function to every entry in the array it cannot be faster than O(N), where N = # elements.  You can parallelize if you have multiple cores, but a single core can't do better by context switching.

Comment: You don't have an iterator, you have an array.

Comment: According to the docs, `A` can be `(…, M, M)` and `B` `(…, M,)`.  In your case that means making (2000,2,2) and (2000,2) arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arr= np.arange(2000)   # array!

A_11 = function_A11(arr)
A_12 = function_A12(arr)
A_21 = function_A21(arr)
A_22 = function_A22(arr)

B_1 = function_B1(arr)
B_2 = function_B2(arr)
```

combine

```
AA = np.array([[A_11,A_12],[A_21, A_22]])
```

I expect `AA.shape` to be (2,2,2000).

```
A = AA.transpose(2,0,1)
```

to get a (2000,2,2) that `solve_ivp` can use.

I haven't tested this.

Comment: You should transpose `B` too. From the doc, if `A.shape==(2000,2,2)` then it should be that `B.shape==(2000,2)`. and then OP can use `X = np.linalg.solve(A,B.T)`.. To the OP: if your arrays are integer arrays, you should convert them to `float`, or else the result may differ.

Comment: With the comment above, it perfectly works!